# How do we choose which answer to accept from a set of high quality answers?

Tags: discussion

I have recently [posted a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/does-the-drunk-man-fall-off-the-cliff-a-random-walk-problem) which was met with several excellent answers of roughly equivalent quality.
This lead me to look for guidelines on how to choose which answer to accept.
Should I favor earlier answers, more creative answers, simpler answers?
I was surprised to find no information about this either on this meta or in the site help pages.

What does the community think: how should we choose which answer to accept when a question has been given several answers of high quality?

Answer (score 8):

I think when accepting an answer, it's worthwhile to keep in mind that this site is *not* about being *fastest to win/solve*. It is not a competition, albeit *challenges* seem to imply this.

I think if you want to accept *for the community* you should aim at having the answer accepted, which *best* answers the question. Imagine somebody finding your post months/years later and *only* reading your question and the accepted answer. Will it be a good experienced for the reader?

Comment: This is how I would tend to think about it myself. I am happy to know that at least someone else agrees.

Answer (score 4):

You can accept whichever answer appeals most to you. In general, you should accept the best answer. If that sounds subjective, it is. I suggest the answer that best explains the solution, breaking ties by oldest answer.

See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on main meta.

Comment: Ah! So you're saying that the important factor to you is clarity of the exposition?

Comment: Yes, I would argue clarity of explanation is the most important aspect of answers on this site. We are here to help others, after all.

Comment: You know what's funny? Over on Physics.SE the idea that we're there to "help others" is really not the accepted mentality. Glad to know it is here.

Comment: Excellent answer, summarising exactly what answer acceptance is all about. Is there a main meta post you can link to too?

Comment: @rand See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: now it has reached me as well... I have a queasy feeling about my accpetion