# How do we want to use our meta FAQ?

Tags: discussion, meta, meta-faq

As far as I know, this isn't something that's ever really been talked about. We've got a potentially extremely useful resource on Puzzling Meta: the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. But I'm not sure how we should use it. Documenting tips, information, puzzle requirements, what-to-do/what-not-to-do questions, etc. could potentially all belong here. Tools and resources we want in a shared way that may not be as suited for being on-site resources. Site policy, important past discussions, etc.

It's a broad topic, but it's, again, potentially extremely valuable as a resource. I've asked a [Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290991/are-there-best-practices-for-individual-sites-to-use-their-per-site-meta-faq-t) about how the Meta FAQ should be used, but ultimately, it's up to you all.

(How) should we set up and use this resource?

Answer (score 6):

**Let's use it for ... well, frequently asked questions!** Sorry, that probably sounds trite. To put it another way, here's the question all active PSE users should be asking themselves for this post:

> Which meta posts do I need to link to most frequently?

Whether it's to educate newer users in site policies or to teach/remind ourselves about them, I'm sure we all have some meta.PSE posts that we link to much more often than others. I've attempted a list and a rough categorisation below, but will be coming back to edit and improve it as I think of more.

---

**Close reasons** - useful for helping people understand why their question was closed.

- [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2783/5373)
- [Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/5373)

**What (Not) To Do posts** - useful for helping people to make better puzzles.

- [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/5373)
- [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712/5373)
- ['What is an XYZ item™?' Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5811/5373)

***Official* site policies** - just important to know, and help explain why certain actions were taken.

- [A policy on plagiarism](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348/5373)
- [How not to be a spammer (redux)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4340/5373)
- [Is it acceptable to post a puzzle from another source and edit in attribution only once it's solved?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5539/5373)

***Unofficial* site policies** - more things that are important to know, and frequently asked about.

- [Can I make up puzzles for the site?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4534/5373)
- [Is it appropriate to pose a puzzle where I don't know the answer?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930/5373)
- [Is the distinction too subtle between downvoting and voting to close?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5478/5373)
- [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799/5373)
- [Should (and/or are) top voted answers (allowed to) use spoiler tags](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1359/5373)
- [How do we choose which answer to accept from a set of high quality answers?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1732/5373)

**Fortnightly topic challenges** - again, frequently asked about by people unfamiliar with them.

- [What should the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges be? (with updates!)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)

Comment: I'm also tempted to suggest [Is it time for us to disallow challenge-only questions?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1601/5373), on the grounds that "*What was this scope dispute / TMBMP / Great Puzzling War I keep hearing about?*" is a frequently asked question :-)

Comment: "What is TSL / The Sphinx's Lair?"  (To clarify, this is a followup on someone else's comment (humn?) elsewhere, that we reference TSL in answers somewhat frequently but people don't necessarily know what that is, and it generally lacks any indication of what it means or how to find it)

Comment: @Rubio When referring people to chat who aren't already familiar with it, I always try to provide a link. You can actually do this automatically just by putting `[chat]` in a comment, though I usually prefer to link directly to the chatroom.